# Exception when call PyModule_GetDict() with a specific python import

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I want manage a LCD from my C code doing calls to python. I'm newbie in that.
My python app works perfectly with LCD. No problems with libraries that are used in my python code. Python2.7
My problem ocurrs when I call to PyModule_GetDict function. If I added a specific library import into python file, my C program crash.
The library is Adafruit_ILI9341, and if I not import it, the C program runs correct.

Is it possible that there are incompatible libraries with Python interpeter?
How I can debug this problem?

Thanks a lot!

This is my C code:

```
// Set PYTHONPATH TO working directory
setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);

PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *presult;
// Initialize the Python Interpreter
Py_Initialize();

// Build the name object
pName = PyString_FromString((char*)"lcd");

// Load the module object
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

// pDict is a borrowed reference 
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

// pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, (char*)"initLCD");

if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
    printf("Let's give this a shot!\n");
    presult=PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,NULL);
    PyErr_Print();
} else {
    PyErr_Print();
}
printf("Result is %d\n",PyInt_AsLong(presult));

// Clean up
Py_DECREF(pModule);
Py_DECREF(pName);

// Finish the Python Interpreter
Py_Finalize();
```

and this is the python code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
import os
import threading
from threading import Timer

import Adafruit_ILI9341 as ADAFRUIT_TFT
import Adafruit_GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import RPi.GPIO as LCD_GPIO

import time
import locale

def iniciaDisplay():
    LCD_GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    LCD_GPIO.setmode(LCD_GPIO.BCM)
    LCD_GPIO.setup(5, LCD_GPIO.OUT)
    p = LCD_GPIO.PWM(5, 100)
    p.start(1)
    DC = 24
    RST = 25
    SPI_PORT = 0
    SPI_DEVICE = 0

    disp = ADAFRUIT_TFT.ILI9341(DC, rst=RST, spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE, max_speed_hz=64000000))
    disp.begin()
    disp.clear()
    disp.display(getLogo(0))

    return 0
```

---

EDIT:

Following the advices of @BlackJack I added the NULL check and PyErr_Print and I saw why it fails. The problem is caused by a _io library import.
This is the output checking NULL values and PyErr_Print:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pruebas/DESFIREXip32/tft.py", line 18, in <module>
    import Adafruit_ILI9341 as ADAFRUIT_TFT
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_ILI9341/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_ILI9341/ILI9341.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .npyio import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import format
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 141, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
SystemError: _PyImport_FixupExtension: module _io not loaded
```

I think this error should treat it in a new thread.

Comment: In the title it says *exception* but in the text is says *crash* - which is it? You are not checking the result of the `PyImport_Import()` call.

Comment: @BlackJack I don't know if is a exception. If I add import Adafruit_ILI9341 in python file, my C program close when call PyModule_GetDict(pModule) function

Comment: Again: you are not checking the result of the `PyImport_Import()` call.

Comment: [What does "SystemError: _PyImport_FixupExtension: module yourmodule not loaded" mean?](http://www.effbot.org/pyfaq/what-does-systemerror-pyimport-fixupextension-module-yourmodule-not-loaded-mean.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least five problems, with all but two being not checking for `NULL` values.

You are not checking the return value of `PyImport_Import()`.  If there is a problem/exception while importing the `lcd` module your code continues as if nothing happened.

Also the return value of `PyDict_GetItemString()` isn't really checked against `NULL`.  `PyCallable_Check()` is applied, but it is somewhat redundant because `PyObject_CallObject()` already checks if the argument is callable.

Of course you are not checking the return value of `PyObject_CallObject()` if it is `NULL`.

`PyErr_Print()` is potentially called even when there is no error/exception which the documentation clearly states will cause a fatal error.

Finally `PyInt_AsLong()` is called with a potentially uninitialized `presult` pointer.  And given the example code it is definately uninitialized because the Python code contains no `initLCD()` so `pFunc` is `NULL` and `presult` never gets assigned a value.

So you better initialize each pointer to `NULL` and check each and every return value.

```
PyObject *pName = NULL;
PyObject *pModule = NULL;
PyObject *pFunc = NULL;
PyObject *presult = NULL;

setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
Py_Initialize();

if ((pName = PyString_FromString("lcd"))) {
    if ((pModule = PyImport_Import(pName))) {   
        if ((pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "initLCD"))) {
            if ((presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL))) {
                printf("Result is %d\n", (int) PyInt_AsLong(presult));
            }
        }
    }
}
if (PyErr_Occurred()) PyErr_Print();

Py_XDECREF(presult);
Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
Py_XDECREF(pModule);
Py_XDECREF(pName);

Py_Finalize();
```

Comment: Thanks @BlackJack. The last night I added the NULL check and PyErr_Print and I saw why it fails, but not seems easy to fix. I'm coding other modules and I forgotten comment here.

Comment: I edited my question, but I think that I must open new question for this